# Parse JSON Response REST android

Tags: java, android, json, rest, android-annotations

I am new to android annotation , i have multiple confusions regarding REST client implementation of AA api.Here is my code i am using:

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "http://something.com", converters = {MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class})

public // if defined, the url will be added as a prefix to every request
interface RESTClient extends RestClientHeaders {
    @Post("/isec/api/user/login ")
    @Accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    void LoginUser(@Field String email,@Field String password,@Field String type);
}
```

and Expected JSON response is :

```
{
"status": false
"message": "Verify your account to continue"
"verified": "n"
"type": "STUDENT"
"apikey": "4o0k8sg4g8ckkswskkowcog80gog4gso0g00kogo"
}
```

Now my questions are :

1 - In which variable i get the response `JSON` ?

2 - What is the best possible way to Parse my response `JSON` , because i get different responses on different parameters of same URL , so i cannot create a class to deal with response ?

3 - What is main difference between `@Path` , `@field` annotation ?

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm suggesting using library called retrofit2. It will simplify your life. No need to parse the json response, and no need to think hard about asynchronous request.

Comment: while searching i've seen lot of people suggesting retrofit2 , but too be honest i didn't find much of a difference between these two libraries , but still can you give easy to understand and follow tutorials on retrofit2 , so i could check that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "http://something.com", converters = {MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class})

public // if defined, the url will be added as a prefix to every request
interface RESTClient extends RestClientHeaders {
    @Post("/isec/api/user/login ")
    @Accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    YourResponseClass LoginUser(@Field String email,@Field String password,@Field String type);
}
```

The response will be parsed into your class with Jackson in this case.

`@Path` is for url variables, `@Field` is for form inputs. The first are substitued into the URL, the second is added in the request body as form url encoded parameters. Please read the wiki, it has detailed examples.

Comment: can you give any example regarding `YourResponseClass` , if i have to create this class what will be its boilerplate w.r.t given response , if so then do i have to create new response class for each different type of responses ?

Comment: Yes, sometimes a few request can give same response json stucture, but sometimes it's not.

Comment: It is a pretty bad design then. Then you have to process the response dynamically. Or maybe you can try a polymorphic deserialization if it fits the case: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization

Comment: it's bit too much to digest for a beginner i think .